# Dynamic Mongoose Schema from JSON Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a JSON object, nothing complex it's just simple keys and values and the link of the added images in array, the model looks like this:

```
{
  "Model": "VolkSwagen",
  "Year": 1995,
  "Fuel Type": "Diesel",
  "Colour": "Black",
  "Nr. of KM": "123",
  "UserCategory": "5123.32",
  "Data": "2021/05/04",
  "userId": "108982948403943427748",
  "AddedImages": [
    "uploads/1617923198614_image2.jpg",
    "uploads\\1617923201585_image5.jpg"
  ]
}
```

The main problem is that these keys and values are added by users so it's dynamic. I want to save these values as a Product in my mongoDB database but I don't know how to create a schema from it. I tried to use npm generate-schema package and SO answers but it didn't work with my collection it were created only nested objects.

My code

```
import GenerateSchema from 'generate-schema'
import mongoose from "mongoose";


export const generateProductSchema = (product) => {
    const productSchema = GenerateSchema.mongoose(product)
    return mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
};

export const uploadProduct = (req,res) => {
        const ProductModel = generateProductSchema(req.body)
        const product = new ProductModel(req.body)

        product.save((err) => {
            if(err) return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err  });
            res.status(200).json({ success:true });
        })


};
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. I sent from my client an already parsed JSON file, but the generate schema accepts only objects. So you basically have to send your object and the generate schema will do the rest

The code

```
import gs from 'generate-schema'
import mongoose from "mongoose";


export const generateProductSchema = (product) => {
    const productSchema =gs.mongoose(product);
    return mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
};
```